# PTXdist + Linux ARM - PCIe not coming up

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, firmware, pci, arch-arm

I've been building a board support package in PTXdist for a Marvell Armada CortexA9 - based embedded system. For now all hardware seems to be working, except for the PCIe - bus.

I'm running a Linux 4.9.58 kernel with the built-in 'armada-clearfog-388' device tree, this is how Bus Support is currently configured:

```
Bus Support
---------------
[*] PCI support
[*] PCI Express Port Bus support
[*]   Root Port Advanced Error Reporting support
[*]   PCI Express ASPM control
-*- Message Signaled Interrupts (MSI and MSI-X) 
    PCI host controller drivers  --->
    [*] Marvell EBU PCIe controller
```

However, running 'lspci' still results in an empty output: the two minipcie - slots and the installed wifi card do not show up. The driver I selected (mvebu-pcie) also doesn't seem to get loaded at boot (it does not appear in dmesg). I cannot seem to be able to modprobe the driver either, since it cannot be compiled as module ([M]).

I've been trying all kinds of configuration combinations for the last couple of days, but none of them gave a positive result. Does anyone have a possible lead on how to fix this? Do I need something extra in userspace to get PCI(e) support?